# "collapse all' or "toggle outline" in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

A new feature in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 is 'outlining' (the ability to collapse regions).  It is awesome.  However, by default all regions are expanded.  I can't seem to find a way to 'collapse all' (also called 'toggle outline' in Visual Studio).  Is anyone aware of a way to do this?  I've been tasked with reviewing a 3,000 line stored procedure, and collapsing regions one-by-one is cumbersome.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It appears this feature does not exist.  It has been recommended to Microsoft.  I suggest voting it up;
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=368542

As a work-around, I'm using Notepad++ to edit locally.  Its region identification isn't as good, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Another halve implemented feature... Common MS, get it right!

Comment: 2017 Update. The feature DOES exist.  It's under the 'Edit' menu, then 'Outlining', then 'Toggle All Outlining'.  Just make sure the focus is in the text editor for the script. Initially, it will collapse everything into a single node, then you can just expand that node and you'll have all your top-level nodes collapsed.

Comment: As Triynko mentions, this feature is now available. However, it is not assigned a keyboard shortcut. See Pakk's answer below for details on setting keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 44):

This isn't a shortcut key, but there is a menu option in the Query Editor to do this.

Open your query and then go to Edit > Outlining > Toggle All Outlining.

This will toggle (i.e. expand/collapse) all nodes in the query.

Answer (score 9):

A workaround is to use BEGIN and END.

```
BEGIN -- comment on/explain the region/outlined section

/*

TSQL goes here

*/

END
```

You will then be able to collapse the BEGIN.

Comment: Thanks for the creative answer.  However, doing this only creates a single collapsed 'root' section.  I was looking for a way to collapse all sections down so it was easier to read.

Comment: Awesome answer, you can use 'begin' 'end' than inner and outer that you want, i mean childs begin end!'s.

Answer (score 7):

In ssms 2017 -> There is an option in Tools > Options {see image}

The below illustrates  @Triynko update to @Shawns answer

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a free 3rd party add-in for SSMS called, SSMS Tools Pack. It provides several useful features, which includes collapsable regions and debug sections. By default, the regions are collapsed when you first open a .sql script.

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=9

For example:

```
--#region You can place comments here which are visible when the region is collapsed.

if object_id('MyTable') is null
begin
   create table MyTable 
   (
   constraint [pk_mytable] primary key clustered ( mytable_id ),
   mytable_id int not null  
   );
end;

--#endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open a .sql script in Visual Studio then you can collapse the code in there.

Comment: visual studio 2015 professional edition does not obey Ctrl + M /O command for .sql file

Answer (score 1):

In my condition it was "Maximun Script Size" default is 1MB, mine was above 1Mb changed it to 5MB it works

Path is

Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> TransactSQL >> Intellisense >> Maximum Script Size

Answer (score 1):

An option that I found helpful...

**Edit.ToggleAllOutlining**

In SSMS 2019 -> Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, then click on command Edit.ToggleAllOutlining and Assign your new shortcut keys.
[Screenshot of Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PofOa.png)

[Screenshot of Caution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKqKJ.png)

I used Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T.

Then put a GO in the beginning of Query and GO after any region I wanted collapsed.  I tried BEGIN END, but it collapsed entire Query.

Try it out with the following:

```
/*
Toggle using Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
Search for "Toggle"
Select Edit.TogleAllOutlining
Enter Global Shortcut key.  Do not use common keys like ctrl-A, ctrl-c, ctrl-v, etc...
    Pay attention to "Shortcut currently used by: (dropdown values)"

I used ctrl-k, ctrl-t
*/  
GO

    --Do something
    Declare @Something varchar(max)
GO
    /*First Region*/    
    select 'parent - this will be toggled'
    
    select 'sub query - toggled with parent'
GO
    /*Second Region*/   
    select 'parent - this will be toggled too'
    
    select 'sub query - toggled with parent'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+M,Ctrl+A is the default in SSMS 17.X.

You can change this by going to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, then click on command Edit.CollapseAllOutlining and Assign your new shortcut keys.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

collapse / decollapse all in visual studio 2022

Answer (score -1):

This feature was implemented in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and is available for editions beyond also using CTRL + M etc - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: These keyboard shortcuts do not apply to the Query Editor. **CTRL+M** will toggle the 'Include Actual Execution Plan' and **CTRL+L** will 'Display Estimated Execution Plan'.