# MS SQL Management Studio 2008 R2 SP1 + SSMS tools. Not collapsing begin/end regions

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, ssms

After updating MS SQL Server 2008 to `R2 SP1`, I'm not able to collapse begin/end sections. (trying SSMS feature to add `--#region`, but it is still very annoying when you're working with huge SQL files).

Output for `SELECT @@VERSION` is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64>
(Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

In `Tools->Options->Text Editor->Transact-SQL->IntelliScense` everything is checked.

Can't see any suggestions pressing `ctrl + space` (so I suppose intellisense isn't working at all?

Anyone had same issue? Do you have any idea where should I look?

Thank you

Comment: Do you get intellisense OK? i.e. is it actually parsing your code?

Comment: What version is the database server you're connecting to? Collapsing code/intellisense only works when you're connected to a SQL2008 server (or later)

Comment: I find this behavior much more reliable and predictable in SQL Server 2012's version of Management Studio. The first iteration is very quirky. Although I don't find it perfect in 2012 either...

Comment: This may help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850389/collapse-all-or-toggle-outline-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008

Comment: If IntelliSense isn't working at all, see http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/ (the title says Management Studio 2012 but most of the article applies to 2008/R2 as well).

Comment: @praveen the accepted answer does not seem accurate. This is SQL Server Management Studio 2008 : http://i.stack.imgur.com/tEMSJ.png

Comment: Just now i tried with my test environment .Collapsing actually works with DML when we use BEGIN and END but if  we need feature like #region and #endregion just like in visual studio there is tool called regions which can be downloaded from http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=9

Comment: @AaronBertrand : In order to wrap the declare statements ,you should be using Go command.

Comment: @praveen #region does work as part of SSMSTools, but what I really need is begin/end. Have lots to read, once will find solution, will post it here. Thank you guys

Comment: @praveen what are you talking about? I wasn't trying to get syntax help. I was just demonstrating that collapsible regions are present in Management Studio - the "answer" you posted (from a question posted in 2009) stated the feature wasn't yet available.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : my mistake for not understanding it properly

Comment: I have the same issue... i have 2 versions of SSMS. both are 2008 R2. The specific version (help-> about) is 10.50.4000.0, this one DOES NOT do collapsing begin/ends. The other version of SSMS is 10.50.1617.0 and it does do the collapsing properly. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this in SSMS08 as far as I know.